# Are any alien species loyal to the pro-human Galactic Empire?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Of the multitudes of non-human subjects of the Galactic Empire, which species are generally loyal to the New Order and thus pro-Empire despite the discrimination? Do these species enjoy an absence or at least lessened discrimination by Imperial authorities?

Thrawn doesn't count because he was an exception (albeit the most brilliant) in the Empire who came from a nation outside Imperial territory.

Comment: Do the Noghri count? (at least until Leia revealed the empire's treachery towards them). http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noghri

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer. It seems like you have never accepted an answer for the vast majority of your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alien species who supported the Empire:

1. The [Noghri](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Noghri)
2. The [Ailon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ailon_(species))
3. The [Chevins](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chevin/Legends)
4. [Devarians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Devaronian/Legends)
5. Many [Rodians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rodian/Legends) served the Empire as Bounty Hunters, Rodians are known as good bounty hunters. Most did it for the money, rather than loyalty for the Empire.
6. The [Muuns](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Muun/Legends)
7. The [Umbarans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Umbaran/Legends)
8. The [Trandoshans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Trandoshan/Legends)
9. [Flakax](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Flakax)
10. The Company SoroSuub which was run by [Sullustans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sullustan/Legends) was a early supporter of the Empire, although a fair number of Sullustans joined the rebellion

(By the way, [this](https://boards.theforce.net/threads/alien-races-allied-with-the-empire.50003617/) is a great discussion about species loyal to the Empire. It has some species that I haven't mentioned)

A couple of these links seem to show that most aliens at least received less discrimination (and some received none at all) than alien species that were not willfully allies of the Empire.

Comment: Doesn't address "Do these species enjoy an absence or at least lessened discrimination by Imperial authorities?"

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add on [Zeltrons](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zeltron) (as seen in [SW: Squadrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Squadrons)) and the [Pantorans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pantoran/Legends). The [Chiss](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chiss) count as well, because there goals happened to align with the empire.